# In C#, what is the best way to sort a list of objects by a string property and get correct order?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a list of "Issue" objects and i want to sort them by the "Priority" field.

The issue is that "Priority" is a string name like "HIGH", "MEDIUM" so i don't have an Id that i can sort by.  How do I sort and tell the sorter that "HIGH" is higher than  "MEDIUM" which is higher than "LOW" ?

Comment: Create a mapping dictionary with matching int values, and sort by looking up the corresponding values from the given string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The obvious way would be:

```
string[] priorities = {  "LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH" };

var orderedIssues = issues.OrderByDescending
              (issue => Array.IndexOf(priorities, issue.Priority));
```

But consider using an enumeration:

```
public enum Priority
{
    Low,
    Medium,
    High
}

var orderedIssues = issues.OrderByDescending
              (issue => (Priority)Enum.Parse(typeof(Priority), issue.Priority, true));
```

Even better would be using the enumeration type as the type of the property / field itself, in which case it's as simple (and less prone to error) as:

```
var orderedIssues = issues.OrderByDescending(issue => issue.Priority);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be like:

```
private static int MapPriority(string priority)
{
  switch(priority.ToUpperInvariant())//skip the case bit if safe
  {
    case "HIGH":
      return 1;
    case "MEDIUM":
      return 2;
    case "LOW":
      return 3;
    default:
      return 4;
  }
}

var sorted = someCollection.OrderBy(i => MapPriority(i.PriorityProperty));
```

With a db-backed form you'll need a function in the DB you can call into. This is in-memory only.

With lots of possible values, I'd base it on a dictionary rather than hand-code. I'd hand-code for three as in this case though (unless the values used could change, a further complication making dictionary-based approaches the only way).

If sorting a serious number of such items, or calling this a lot, I'd go with an `IComparer<T>` implementation, or have the item itself implement `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: There are easier and cleaner ways than a switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could, in this specific case, also use Linq's `OrderBy` method:

```
var sortedList = issueList.OrderBy(i=>
                    i.Priority == "HIGH" 
                       ? 1 
                       : i.Priority == "MEDIUM" 
                          ? 2 
                          : 3).ToList();
```

As a one-liner this wouldn't be too bad. You could also put the strings into an array, list or Dictionary in the order you want them sorted (or containing the sort order as the Value in the case of the Dictionary).

The one downside of using OrderBy is that it doesn't affect the source List unless you tell it to by reassigning the List to the result. In all cases, it will create two additional collections; an internally-used array or list within OrderBy (sorts have to have knowledge of the entire collection they're sorting) and the List produced by ToList(). So, this will require O(2N) additional memory, while List.Sort() could be in-place (not sure if it actually is, but it does use QuickSort which is normally in-place).

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Priority
{
    LOW = 1,
    MEDIUM = 2,
    HIGH = 3
}

issues.OrderByDescending(issue=>issue.Priority);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
List<Issue> issues = ...;

var result = issues.OrderBy(x=> x.Priority=="HIGH"?1:x.Priority=="MEDIUM"?2:3);
```

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote, but you're sorting an array of the strings that would be used as priorities. This would have no effect whatsoever on any list of Issue objects that have these priorities, as was stated in the OP.

Comment: @KeithS Ah, good point. Didn't pay attention about the "Issue" objects. Will correct. I was more concerned on showing how to create a mapping on one line...

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution is a dictionary with indexes:

```
var priorities = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "HIGH", 0 },
    { "MEDIUM", 1 },
    { "LOW", 2 }, // You can also use a non-complete priority list (for example without "LOW")
};
// Order by priorities, if priorities doesn't contains string value, push item to end.
var result = issues
    .OrderBy(x => priorities.GetValueOrDefault(key: x.Priority, defaultValue: priorities.Count + 1))
    .ToList();
```

Also I decided to create a small open source [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kurnakov.PriorityOrder) library to solve this problem.

Installation

```
dotnet add package Kurnakov.PriorityOrder
```

Code example

```
using PriorityOrder;

var result = issues
    .OrderByPriority(x => x.Priority, "HIGH", "MEDIUM", "LOW") // Or with IEnumerable<string>
    .ToList();
```

More details you can find [here](https://github.com/kurnakovv/PriorityOrder)

P.S. You can also use enums instead strings, I talked about it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77618384/22817151)