# Sort a list based on subjective values

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Say I have this list of precious rocks: `Adamantite, Diamonds, Crystal, Gold, Silver, Bronze`.

Each rock is an object which has a property named `Rarity` which is a string based on either or these values: `Common, Precious, Rare,  Mythic, Infinite`.

I would like to sort my list based on these values where `Common` is the least precious and `Infinite` is the most precious. Is there any way using linq that I can achieve this easily, or do I need to pop a new method just for this case? I would also love to be able to sort from most precious to less.

Thanks!

Comment: Enumeration?  Sorted from least to greatest rarity, you could compare rarities based on the value of the string in the enumeration.

Comment: See: [In C#, what is the best way to sort a list of objects by a string property and get correct order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199668/in-c-what-is-the-best-way-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-by-a-string-property-and-g)

Comment: Yeah, I kinda thougth that an enum would eventually be the answer, it's just that there are times when I will need to do otherwise because the values are not as "shapeable" as this example. Thanks @Ani btw!

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest using an enum instead of a string.  Then you can simply order the values in the enum according to their rarity, and ordering should then "just work."

Alternatively, consider implementing an [`IComparer<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) that will order the strings per your requirements.  You can then use the [`Enumerable.OrderBy()` overload that takes an `IComparer<TKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx).

Comment: That's a good point. In this case, you are very right, I should change the value to an enum. I'll work on that. And I did not know about `Icomparer`, that's a sound advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an enum, just create a custom comparing method, something like this:

```
{
...
List rocks = GetRocks();

List sortedRocks = rocks.OrderBy(a => a, new RockComparer()).ToList();
...
}

public class RockComparer : IComparer<string> 
{ 
    public int Compare(Rock x, Rock y) 
    { 
        ... (implement your comparing functionality here) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is what I would do. Although I would use `List<Rock>`, which has a `Sort(IComparer<Rock>)` method.