# C# Sort List by Enum

Tags: c#, sorting, enums

I have got a list of Entity, which has got an enum.

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }

    public string CarName { get; set; }

    public CarCategory CarCategory { get; set; }
}

public enum CarCategory
{
    None = 0,
    kLowRange = 1,
    kMidRange = 2,
    kHighRange = 3
}
```

Now I have got a list of Cars, I would like to use Comparer and run it on the enum such that all the entity having CarCategory as kMidRange and kHighRange will be sorted to first in the list.

I have tried with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309576) but havent found any luck.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I kinda have got the mistake I am doing. I was looking at

```
var sortedList = carList
  .OrderBy(x => x.CarCategory, 
                new EnumComparer<CarCategory> {
                  CarCategory.kMidRange, 
                  CarCategory.kHighRange});
```

But was getting only same values. I have to add .ToList() in order to get the result.

```
var sortedList = carList
  .OrderBy(x => x.CarCategory, 
                new EnumComparer<CarCategory> { 
                  CarCategory.kMidRange, 
                  CarCategory.kHighRange})
  .ToList();
```

Will give me the expected results. My mistake!

Comment: Do you want to sort the original `List<Car>` or do you want an ordered sequence like `cars.OrderByDescending(car => (int)car.CarCategory)`?

Comment: It seems like `var sorted = cars.OrderBy(c => c.CarCategory).ToList();` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Xander, Please share the *use* & *Implementation* of your Comparer, and it'd be vastly easier to assist.

Comment: `var sortedCars = cars.OrderBy(c=>(int)c.Carcategory);` or you can find another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199668/in-c-what-is-the-best-way-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-by-a-string-property-and-g)

Comment: OrderByDescending, or possibly with a bit more complexity in there if he really wants mid to come before high, as his question kind of implies.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`enum` is effectively *integer* (`int` in your case)

> The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int,
> uint, long, or ulong.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx for details.

Since `CarCategory` implementation has the items in the *desired order* you can put just

```
 var sortedList = carList
   .OrderByDescending(x => (int) (x.CarCategory))
   .ToList();
```

please, note `Descending`: you want `kHighRange` to be on the *top*. If you want an *arbitrary order*, e.g.

```
kMidRange, kHighRange, None, kLowRange
```

I suggest using *mapping*:

```
 // desired order: None should be 3d, LowRange 4th, MidRange 1st, HighRange 2nd 
 int[] map = new[] {3, 4, 1, 2};

 var sortedList = carList
   .OrderBy(x => map[(int) (x.CarCategory)])
   .ToList();
```

Comment: @Roma: it can be `{2,3,0,1}` or even `{123, 45678, -14, 72}`... we just compare *integers* (map enum value to corresponding integer value); all we want is `map[2] < map[3] < map[0] < map[1]`

Comment: Just as a note, this won't work for LINQ to Entities, you'll get a "The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ" error

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I want to complement [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552327/22817151)

**Problems**

1. If the enam numeration is not sorted
2. If the number of the value may go beyond the boundaries of the `map` array
3. If `map` array hasn't some numbers (when you add value to enum, but not add value to `map` array)

Than we get `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`

For example

```
public enum CarCategory
{
    None = 0,
    kLowRange = 30,
    kMidRange = 2000,
    kHighRange = 10,
    kAnotherRangeCarCategory = 10000,
}
```

Than use Dmitry code

```
// desired order: None should be 3d, LowRange 4th, MidRange 1st, HighRange 2nd 
 int[] map = new[] {2000, 10, 0, 30};

 var sortedList = carList
   .OrderBy(x => map[(int) (x.CarCategory)])
   .ToList();
```

Exception

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
```

**Solution**

```
var map = new Dictionary<CarCategory, int>() {
    { CarCategory.kMidRange, 0 },
    { CarCategory.kHighRange, 1 },
    { CarCategory.None, 2 },
    { CarCategory.kLowRange, 3 }
    // without "kAnotherRangeCarCategory"
};
// Order by map, if map doesn't contains enum value, push item to end.
var sortedList = carList
   .OrderBy(x => map.GetValueOrDefault(key: x.CarCategory, defaultValue: map.Count + 1)) 
   .ToList();
```

This code work's correct and not throw `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`

P.S. You can also use strings instead enums. I talked about this in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78045482/22817151)

P.P.S I decided to create a small open source [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kurnakov.PriorityOrder) library to solve this problem.

Installation

```
dotnet add package Kurnakov.PriorityOrder
```

Code example

```
using PriorityOrder;

var priorities = new List<CarCategory>()
{
    CarCategory.kMidRange,
    CarCategory.kHighRange,
    CarCategory.None,
    CarCategory.kLowRange,
    // without "kAnotherRangeCarCategory"
};
var sortedList = carList
   .OrderByPriority(x => x.CarCategory, priorities) // or with params[]
   .ToList();
```

More details you can find [here](https://github.com/kurnakovv/PriorityOrder)